# How much volume should I increase or decrease based on the Gain and Peak obtained by trackGain?

Tags: production-audio

Below is the code to get gain and peak.

```
TrackGain trackGain = new TrackGain(44100, 16);
foreach (sampleSet in track) {
trackGain.AnalyzeSamples(leftSamples, rightSamples)
}
double gain = trackGain.GetGain();
double peak = trackGain.GetPeak();
```

Let's say I get gain of 5.34 and peak of 1.33

How can I determine the volume adjustment that I need to make for that track? A formula to determine would be great.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the software you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Replay Gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain) recommends a target loudness of 89 dB sound pressure level. So, using an available library like [nReplayGain](https://github.com/kmcclellan/NReplayGain) to determine the gain needs to be adjusted to our custom target loudness.

So, if we want to target 92.8 dB we add 3.8 dB to the gain that we computed for our track.